# Reshaping multiple columns with disordered values

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape2

I have a dataset with multiple columns that I want to reshape. Essentially, the data from the columns corresponding to the numerals become columns taking their corrsponding value in that row from the columns `v1:v12`.

I have tried:

```
tt2 <- melt(tt, id.vars=c(1:6, 12:16))
tt3 <- melt(tt2, id.vars=c(1:6, 12:13))
names(tt3)[7:10]<-c("content", "names", "data_value", "values")
final_tt <- tt3 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = names, values_from = values)
```

However, the data turns out like this:

```
# A tibble: 500 × 28
    ...1 category   name  price product_url location content data_value `Character:` `Card Size:` `Game:` `Year Manufactu… `Language:` `Graded:`
   <dbl> <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr>       <chr>    <fct>   <fct>      <chr>        <chr>        <chr>   <chr>            <chr>       <chr>    
 1    24 ultra_rare PSA … $1,6… https://ww… toyama,… one     v1         Charizard    NA           NA      NA               NA          NA       
 2   107 english    Shin… $7,4… https://ww… Melbour… one     v1         Charizard    NA           NA      NA               NA          NA       
 3   166 legendary  84/1… £2.99 https://ww… Sheffie… one     v1         Onix         NA           NA      NA               NA          NA       
 4   172 ultra_rare PIKA… $1,0… https://ww… Tiverto… one     v1         Pikachu      NA           NA      NA               NA          NA       
 5   196 legendary  59/1… £1.99 https://ww… Sheffie… one     v1         Primeape     NA           NA      NA               NA          NA       
 6   202 legendary  70/1… £3.99 https://ww… Sheffie… one     v1         Charmander   NA           NA      NA               NA          NA       
 7   287 french     Char… £15.… https://ww… Glossop… one     v1         Charmander   NA           NA      NA               NA          NA       
 8   502 used       Shin… £2,4… https://ww… Melbour… one     v1         Raichu       NA           NA      NA               NA          NA       
 9   945 french     Noeu… £1.50 https://ww… Enfield… one     v1         Exeggcute    NA           NA      NA               NA          NA       
10  2087 french     Noeu… £0.99 https://ww… Enfield… one     v1         Exeggcute    NA           NA      NA               NA          NA       
# … with 490 more rows, and 14 more variables: Card Type: <chr>, Card Number: <chr>, Finish: <chr>, Features: <chr>, Material: <chr>,
#   Rarity: <chr>, Card Condition: <chr>, Manufacturer: <chr>, NA <chr>, Card Name: <chr>, Grade: <chr>, Pokid: <chr>,
```

I thought that given they're in the same row, then their corresponding values should match?

Reproducible code:

```
structure(list(...1 = c(24, 107, 166, 172, 196, 202, 287, 502, 
945, 2087, 2156, 2722, 2725, 2740, 2744, 2774, 2808, 2979, 3012, 
3195), category = c("ultra_rare", "english", "legendary", "ultra_rare", 
"legendary", "legendary", "french", "used", "french", "french", 
"french", "used", "used", "used", "used", "used", "used", "used", 
"used", "used"), name = c("PSA 10 GEM MINT Pokemon Japanese Card 209/150 CHARIZARD GX 2018 Ultra Shiny SSR", 
"Shining Charizard Holo Pokemon Card Unlimited Neo Destiny 107/105 BGS PSA 10 GEM", 
"84/110 | Onix | Legendary | Pokemon Card | Near Mint", "PIKACHU 025 Vintage JAPANESE Jungle Set Pokemon Card -1996 Ultra Rare error Card", 
"59/110 | Primeape | Legendary | Pokemon Card | Played", "70/110 | Charmander | Legendary | Pokemon Card | Near Mint", 
"Charmander - 46/102 - Common - Base Set Unlimited Pokemon Card - French - NM", 
"Shining Raichu Holo Pokemon Card 1st Edition Neo Destiny 111/105 BGS PSA 10", 
"Noeufnoeuf (Exeggcute) 52/64 Jungle French Extremely rare Pokemon Card good cond", 
"Noeufnoeuf (Exeggcute) 52/64 Jungle French Extremely rare Pokemon Card good cond", 
"2013 - Pokemon Card URSARING- PV 130 - Level 1 - 76 / 101- French -N ° 217- TB", 
"Venusaur Holo Pokemon Card 2002 Expedition 6/165 BGS PSA 10 Gem Mint", 
"MINT Squirtle First Edition Stamp Shadowless Pokemon Card 63/102 100% Genuine", 
"MINT Bulbasaur First Edition Stamp Shadowless Pokemon Card 44/102", 
"Charizard Holo Pokemon Card 1999 Original Base Set 4/102 ARK PSA BGS 9 9.5/9/9/9", 
"MINT Charmander First Edition Stamp Shadowless Pokemon Card 46/102 100% Genuine", 
"Entei Gold Star Holo Pokemon Card EX Unseen Forces 113/115 BGS PSA 10 GEM MINT", 
"Charizard 2nd Edition Pokemon Card Holo", "Pokemon Cards Japanese TCG Team Rocket joins! Oid-back PSA10", 
"Pokemon Cards Japanese TCG Pikachu Battle Festa 2014 Promo 090/XY-P PSA10"
), price = c("$1,650.00", "$7,441.48", "£2.99", "$1,000.00", 
"£1.99", "£3.99", "£15.00", "£2,409.05", "£1.50", "£0.99", 
"£4.79", "£1,444.36", "£1,500.00", "£1,500.00", "£1,551.55", 
"£1,500.00", "£1,176.39", "£1,200.00", "£1,122.00", "£1,059.00"
), location = c("toyama, Japan", "Melbourne, Australia", "Sheffield, United Kingdom", 
"Tiverton, Rhode Island, United States", "Sheffield, United Kingdom", 
"Sheffield, United Kingdom", "Glossop, United Kingdom", "Melbourne, Australia", 
"Enfield, United Kingdom", "Enfield, United Kingdom", "Paris, France", 
"Melbourne, Australia", "Newton Aycliffe, United Kingdom", "Newton Aycliffe, United Kingdom", 
"Melbourne, Australia", "Newton Aycliffe, United Kingdom", "Melbourne, Australia", 
"Hove, United Kingdom", "higasiosaksioohasuhigasi, Japan", "higasiosaksioohasuhigasi, Japan"
), one = c("Character:", "Character:", "Character:", "Character:", 
"Character:", "Character:", "Character:", "Character:", "Character:", 
"Character:", "Character:", "Character:", "Character:", "Character:", 
"Character:", "Character:", "Character:", "Character:", "Character:", 
"Character:"), two = c("Card Size:", "Card Size:", "Game:", "Year Manufactured:", 
"Game:", "Game:", "Language:", "Graded:", "Card Type:", "Card Type:", 
"Card Number:", "Finish:", "Features:", "Features:", "Card Size:", 
"Features:", "Material:", "Card Type:", "Card Size:", "Card Size:"
), three = c("Card Number:", "Material:", "Card Number:", "Game:", 
"Card Number:", "Card Number:", "Game:", "Year Manufactured:", 
"Rarity:", "Rarity:", "Card Condition:", "Manufacturer:", NA, 
NA, "Material:", NA, "Year Manufactured:", "Game:", "Card Condition:", 
"Card Name:"), four = c("Card Condition:", "Grade:", "Pokid:", 
NA, "Pokid:", "Pokid:", NA, "Card Type:", NA, NA, "Creature/Monster Type:", 
"Card Size:", NA, NA, "Features:", NA, "Card Type:", NA, "Grade:", 
"Graded:"), five = c("Creature/Monster Type:", "Year Manufactured:", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Finish:", NA, NA, "Card Type:", "Language:", 
NA, NA, "Vintage:", NA, "Finish:", NA, "Vintage:", "Features:"
), v1 = c("Charizard", "Charizard", "Onix", "Pikachu", "Primeape", 
"Charmander", "Charmander", "Raichu", "Exeggcute", "Exeggcute", 
"Ursaring", "Venusaur", "Charmander", "Charmander", "Charizard", 
"Charmander", "Entei", "Charizard", "Team Rocket j", "Pikachu"
), v2 = c("Standard", "Standard", "Pokémon TCG", "1996", "Pokémon TCG", 
"Pokémon TCG", "French", "Yes", "Pokémon", "Pokémon", "217", 
"Holo", "Shadowless", "Shadowless", "Standard", "Shadowless", 
"Card Stock", "Pokémon", "Standard", "Standard"), v3 = c("209/150", 
"Card Stock", "84/110", "Pokémon TCG", "59/110", "70/110", "Pokémon TCG", 
"2002", "Rare", "Rare", "Light Play", "Pokemon", NA, NA, "Card Stock", 
NA, "2005", "Pokémon TCG", "Near Mint", "Pikachu Battle Festa"
), v4 = c("Near Mint", "10", "5455", NA, "5430", "5441", NA, 
"Pokémon", NA, NA, "Adrenarush", "Standard", NA, NA, "Holo", 
NA, "Pokémon", NA, "10", "Yes"), v5 = c("Dragon", "2002", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "Holo", NA, NA, "Team Plasma", "English", NA, 
NA, "Yes", NA, "Holo", NA, "Yes", "Promo")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the output you are after.